# document.createElement("svg") instanceof SVGElement is false

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, svg

When I tried the code `document.createElement("svg") instanceof SVGElement` in chrome it returns `false`. Why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Creating an element like `<svg>` not in any context and out of thin air will create an *unknown element*. If you want to create an SVG element use:

```
var a = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
```

Now if you compare:

```
var result = a instanceof SVGElement;
```

the `result` will be `true`.

See a working example in this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/K5DSj/)**

Comment: A note for jQuery users: I found that if I retrieve an svg element through jQuery, such as `$('svg')`, it wouldn't be an SVGElement. You have to get the dom element `$('svg').get(0)` in order for `instanceof SVGElement` to be true.